# eclipse skips a number of lines for no apparent reason

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-adt

I am using eclipse. I have a java method that is supposed to paint some images on an android canvas (I don't really think this back story is relevant, but who knows). Since my method is not behaving as expected, I decide to debut. My method looks as follows:

```
List<Stuff> myStuff = …

public Point methodName(Point offset, other params){
    final int nStuff = myStuff.size();

    if (null == myStuff || myStuff.isEmpty() || nStuff > offset.x) {
            return offset;
    }

    //bunch of lines that eclipse completely skip go here
    //here is first of skipped lines
    LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, null);


    //eclipse goes all the way down to here
    return offset;

}
```

What I found blew my mind. For now apparent reason, eclipse just skips a number of lines in my code. I simply jumps over them. No errors. Nothing. Just skipping.

Now, I have NEVER seen this before. And the skipping is consistent: from line 252 to 293.

Comment: Which are lines 252 to 293 in this excerption?

Comment: add some logging in your if statement

Comment: You guys miss the part that I debugged the code line by line and positively watched as eclipsed simply skipped the bunch of codes.